# If there is any need to reference ApplePay.js in my view? if yes than how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, safari, applepay, applepayjs

I am creating a POC for Apple Pay in my web app using .net MVC. I'm following this online tutorial:

https://www.oshyn.com/blogs/2017/01/apple-pay-development

I'm doing this on Windows and I've installed safari browser just for testing.

The documentation says Safari supports Applepay.js but my code is not working on the Safari browser.

I tried to show the alert only if Apple Pay JS API is available in the browser, but not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        if (window.ApplePaySession) {
            alert("Apple js available");
}
```

I just want confirmation that Applejs is actually available in my browser Safari.

Comment: Can you view the network requests? I mean you should check Applepay.js was downloaded. You can also check the version of Safari.

Comment: I just need to confirm that if ApplePay js is suported in windows if i download safari .

Comment: I found this in your tutorial:"Unfortunately it only works with the Safari web browser in Apple's platforms (macOS 10.12+ and iOS 10+)"